# Qt dbus property returning a list

Tags: c++, qt, dbus

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a `dbus` property that is a list of `unsigned short`.  I'm new to `dbus` and `Qt`, and the examples don't cover lists at all.

The XML source looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
  <interface name='com.Controller'>
    <property name="ModeCycle" type="aq" access="readwrite">
      <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.Property.EmitsChangedSignal"
          value="true"/>
      <annotation name="org.qtproject.QtDBus.QtTypeName"
          value="ModeCycleList"/>
    </property>
  </interface>
</node>
```

I originally tried passing in a value of `Qlist<unsigned short`, but qdbusxml2cpp can't handle angle brackets there (and silently drops the entry).  So, I created bits.h with:

```
#include <QtCore/QList>
typedef QList<unsigned short> ModeCycleList;
```

I added:

```
QT += dbus 
QDBUSXML2CPP_INTERFACE_HEADER_FLAGS = -i bits.h
```

to the .pro file to include the typedef and get things to link.

I can't actually run the code yet (missing the other side of the dbus connection), but at least it compiles and links.

Does anyone have a example for a `dbus` list property or know how I should be specifying a list here?

Comment: "... undefined reference to ... " "This doesn't make sense because motor.h includes ..."  - undefined reference means you have a linker issue. It has nothing to do with what you include but everything to do with what object files/libraries you link to.

Comment: You nailed it.  I needed to add some stuff to the .pro file so qmake included the right libraries.
QT += dbus